# Looping all .csv files in one directory through a script, and output the results of each loop into a separate .csv in different directory

Tags: bash

I am struggling to run multiple .csv files from one directory through a script, and sending the output of each to a different directory. I am able to run the .csv files one by one, but I have 100 files that need to go through the script. Individually, it's pretty simple, I am pulling my .csv file from `Test_Folder` and sending the output of the script to `Results`:

```
bash run_example.sh Test_Folder/df1.csv >> Results/results1.csv
```

But when I attempt to run a loop for them all, I get met with some errors due to having different directories. I've tried a few different things:

```
for csvfile in Test_Folder/*.csv;
do
    bash run_example.sh $csvfile >> Results/test_results.csv
done
```

This above obviously works, but `test_results.csv` gets overwritten after each loop.

```
for csvfile in Test_Folder/*.csv;
do
    bash run_example.sh $csvfile >> "Results/results_${csvfile}.csv"
done
```

When trying to run the above, I get met with:

```
bash: Results/results_Test_Folder/df1.csv.csv: No such file or directory
```

So it appears that it's taking the path of `$csvfile` rather than just the file itself. This ends up searching for a directory that clearly doesn't exist. I have a tried a few other variations of the above code, using other SE posts as reference, but I have not seen any post that specifically mentions different directories.

I'm looking for the new directory to be populated with the same amount of `results.csv` files as input files, so `results1.csv`, `results2.csv`, and so on. Even something as simple as a number that gets incremented with each loop and added to the output file name would be perfect. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: `bash run_example.sh $csvfile >> Results/${csvfile#Test_Folder/}.csv` -- you need to strip `"Test_Folder/"` from the front of your filename when looping `for csvfile in Test_Folder/*.csv;` The variable `csvfile` will hold `"Test_Folder/filename.csv"` where you want the output filename to be `"Result/filename.csv"` The parameter-expansion with substring removal will do that for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the comment solved your problem, for completeness, the problem you experienced is due to the loop variable `csvfile` containing the path information for `Test_Folder/`. When you redirect to `Results/results_${csvfile}.csv`, you are actually redirecting to, e.g. `Results/results_Test_Folder/df1.csv.csv`. Where you haven't trimmed `Test_Folder/` from the front of `csvfile` and you have applied the `.csv` extension twice. This results in your exact error:

```
bash: Results/results_Test_Folder/df1.csv.csv: No such file or directory
```

To correct the problem you can use *parameter-expansion with substring removal* to trim `Test_Folder/` from the front of `csvfile` and since the filename already has the `.csv` extension, simply omit it, e.g.

```sh
for csvfile in Test_Folder/*.csv;
do
    bash run_example.sh "$csvfile" >> "Results/results_${csvfile#Test_Folder/}"
done
```

This would result in the redirection for the example you gave for `df1.csv` to:

```
Results/results_df1.csv
```

(**note:** you should quote the original `$csvfile` in `bash run_example.sh "$csvfile" ...`)

The standard parameter-expansions with substring removal provided by POSIX are:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

Note, bash itself provides many, many, many more. See [man 1 bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the **Parameter Expansion** heading.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.